# Get postcode / zip code with Google Geocoding API

Tags: php, google-places-api, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to get the **postcode / zip code** for the registered users of my platform.

I have access to the following:

1. City Name
2. State ID (Administrative Area Level 1)
3. Country ID (Always Australia)
4. Level 2 ID (Administrative Area Level 2)

I am aware of the **Google Geocoding API** but I do not have the full address of the user.

Any assistance on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't have the full address of the user then you're going to find it difficult to get their post code. You could just ask them. Beware of privacy regulations that might affect what you're doing. For Australia you need to consider the Privacy Act 1988. Europe has GDPR, and so on.

Comment: How about using Places Autocomplete API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: How would you find a postal code without the street address?

Comment: @MrUpsidown not sure. is it not possible?

Comment: that would be an ambiguous query. you'd either have to use component filtering or use autocomplete.

Comment: A small city might have only 1 postal code but what about bigger ones? They can have dozens.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I have the city name in the database (small and big).

Comment: Postal codes are linked to a street name and number, not to a city, at least for bigger cities. Let's say you have "New York" in your database. What is the postal code for New York? As far as I can tell, there are 200 different postal codes for New York...

Comment: @MrUpsidown I am aware of that, I do have the name of the smaller cities, not sure if I am able to get the postcode though.